# HTTPS handshake not happening from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpwebrequest, x509certificate

I am having an application in which I am calling an external webservice.
There is a PFX file provided by the provider.
We are attaching the PFX file using `X509Certificate2`.

The application runs from Visual studio IIS express. But when pointed to IIS. It will start throwing `403 Forbidden` error in the same Machine.

We have added the authentication Headers and Network credentials. But in IIS it will not work. The same exact copy works in Visual Studio.

This used to work before from IIS too. But, recently it stopped and it is not running again. Providers say they haven't changed anything.

NOTE: We have another REST service running in the same machine inside the same IIS without any errors. Both service is having similar codes and fiddler also is giving similar requests from Visual studio and IIS

Full error what I get

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden. at
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean, asyncCall) at
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at
Production.CompanyInfoWebService.getCompany(wsNumberRequest compInfoRequest) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\9b73ec26\5a34d414\App_WebReferences._jpe17z6.0.cs:line 477
at _Default.ButtonFetch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\TestWebsites\app_test\Default.aspx.cs:line 61
```

Comment: Simply saying 'attaching' is useless. To let others know how to use the certificate you need to provide more details.

Comment: It appears the server is refusing your connection: what type of authentication is it expecting? (Remember an IIS workers runs under its own identity while IIS Express runs under yours.)